# How to create enum optional instance

Tags: swift

I am leraning Swift 3 from "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3 beta)". Below is their enum example. In the end of this example, they have written "Use the `init?(rawvalue:)` to make an instance of enumeration from a raw value". Can anybody tell me, how to make that. Thanks.

```
enum Rank: Int {

    case ace = 1 // Raw value
    case two, three, four , five , six, seven, eight, nine, ten
    case jack, queen, king

init?(rawValue: Int) {

    self = rawValue == 1 ? .ace : .jack
}

    func simpleDescription() -> String{

        switch self {
        case .ace:

            return "ace"

        case .jack:

            return "jack"

        case .queen:

            return "queen"

        case .king:

            return "king"

        default:

            return String(self.rawValue)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here:

```
enum Rank: Int
```

"your" `Rank` enums raw value must be of type `Int`.

Therefore, to create a new `Rank` element with `ace` value, you would write:

```
let ace = Rank(rawValue: 1)
```

To create a queen you would write:

```
let queen = Rank(rawValue: 12)
```

Notice also that the `Rank` init returns an optional. This means that if you give it an invalid `Int` value, you will get `nil` in return.

For instance:

```
let notValid = Rank(rawValue: 100) //gives you nil in return
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an optional `init` for an enum like so:

```
init?(rawValue: String) {
    if rawValue == "ace" {
        self = .ace
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The `else` handles an invalid / unexpected value in `term` (this is why the init is an optional initialiser - it may return nil if given an invalid input). Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain it also?

Comment: This means, it is a kind of a closure because it is same as defining a function. Am I right?

Comment: @WasimSafdar not really, it's just an optional initialiser (they can also be used in classes). The if statement block is just checking if there's a match for a given input (rawValue). If there is, then it "returns" a specified value (i.e. `case ace`). However, if there isn't, then it can return nil, or, alternatively you could do something like `case unknown`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `init?(rawvalue:)` initializer:

```
let enumValue1 = Rank(rawValue: 100)
print(enumValue1) 
// will print nil because raw value is too big

let enumValue2 = Rank(rawValue: 6)
print(enumValue) 
// will print `Optional(ACNotificationsDemo.Rank.six)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum OptionalValues<T>{
   case None
   case Some(T)
}
var possibleInteger:
OptionalValue<Int>=.None
possibleInteger = .Some(100)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PalaniKrishnan Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.